# How to format SQL comparison in CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, output

I am running two SQL's on two different databases and comparing the results. I am writing the results to a csv file. Currently I am doing a 1 to 1 comparison of the results such that each element in a row of the result set is a row in the csv file.

```
table name | source column | source value | target value | difference type | target column
__________________________________________________________________________________________
Table A      Column A             A001          A001          SAME            Column A
Table A      Column B             A002          B002          Different       Column B
```

These are making the csv files far too long, and I wish to change this output to display each row of the result sets stacked on top of each other like this:

```
A001 A002 A003
A001 B002 A003
```

But I am not sure of a good way to indicate which columns would be different (I cannot color code in a csv file). Adding a column to the end which says which columns are different is an option, but I feel like there must be a better way.

I will also take suggestions on other possible ways to format these results.

Comment: additional info for each row = additional column (even if the content is just single char or symbol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is you final goal.

But first you should include a row_id at begining of each row, also include what db that row is from

Then you may include one aditional character to indicate if they are Equal `E-` or No Equal `N-`

Also a final field to indicate if the rows as a whole are Equal or not

```
rowID   DB  FieldA  FieldB  FieldC Equal
1       A   E-A001  N-A002  E-A003  NO
1       B   E-A001  N-B002  E-A003  NO
```

And if you import that csv in Excel for example you can filter by column where start with `N-`